# Find an example of a function $f(x)$ and a convergent sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ where the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges, but not to $f(x)$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Find an example of a function $f(x)$ and a convergent sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ where the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges, but not to $f(x)$?

I thought that you would have to use a function like $f(x) = \frac {1}{x}$, but then I could not find a sequence where the convergence of $f(x_n)$ did not converge to the same value as $f(x)$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then $\lim f(x_n)=f(\lim x_n)$. Thus, choosing a continuous function for this not going to work

Comment: Do you want this at one value of x or at every x?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n},f(x)=\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & x\neq 0 \\
      1 & x=0
    \end{array}
\end{array}$

Then $f(x_n)=0,f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)=f(0)=1$.

Comment: Wouldn't $f(x_n) = 1$, since $a_n$ converges to 0?

Comment: $x_n \neq 0 \implies f(x_n)=0$, so for each $n$, $f(x_n)=0$.